# Parse.Cloud.httpRequest inconsistency between data and text

Tags: json, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I am running a Parse.Cloud.httpRequest to Google Geocoding API from Parse Cloud Code. 
The request works fine. However, I am unable to retrieve the data.

Request:

```
var url_gg = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='+encodeURI(place)&key=key;
Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({method: 'GET', url: url_gg}).then(function(response){
            console.log(response.text);
            console.log(response.data);
});
```

Here is the log from the response.text

```
"results" : [
  {
     "address_components" : [
        {

       ... (truncated)
```

Here is the log from the response.data

```
{"results":[],"status":"OK"}
```

When I try to JSON.parse(response.text), I get the same result: **the "results" array is empty while it is not empty in the response.text**

How can I get the value of the results array?

Thanks a lot!
Maxime.

**EDIT**: Here is the reponse

```
{"uuid":"b6efde3a-759b-1fa3-46e5...","status":200,"headers":{"Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*","Alt-Svc":"quic=\":443\"; p=\"1\"; ma=604800","Alternate-Protocol":"443:quic,p=1","Cache-Control":"public, max-age=86400","Content-Encoding":"gzip","Content-Type":"application/json; charset=UTF-8","Date":"Fri, 04 Sep 2015 18:10:55 GMT","Expires":"Sat, 05 Sep 2015 18:10:55 GMT","Server":"mafe","Transfer-Encoding":"chunked","Vary":"Accept-Language","X-Frame-Options":"SAMEORIGIN","X-XSS-Protection":"1; mode=block"},"text":"{\n   \"results\" : [\n      {\n         \"address_components\" : [\n            {\n               \"long_name\" : \"1\",\n               \"short_name\" : \"1\",\n               \"types\" : [ \"street_number\" ]\n            },\n            {\n               \"long_name\" : \"Chemin de ...\",\n               \"short_name\" : \"Chemin de ...\",\n               \"types\" : [ \"route\" ]\n            },\n            {\n               \"long_na... (truncated)
enter code here
```

Comment: id review the geo api response types and verify that 'data' is not reserved for special obj types like svg or binary...

Comment: Thank you for your answer @robert. I must admit that I don't fully undertsand it. So I copy pasted the response that I get from Google and httpRequest. Unfortunately it is truncated and don't know how to get the full log. Hope it helps

Comment: "text":"{\n   \"results\"    <-- that is where your json response array is.  You can just take that block of bytes, remove from it the carriage returns and plug it into any json formatter like :  http://json.parser.online.fr/   .. That is your text response from the api.  it may also return binarys like maps...

Comment: @robert When I run JSON.parse(response.text) on Parse Cloud, I get the same result: {"results":[],"status":"OK"} As if the array was erased... I'll investigate further. Thank you Robert.

Comment: @Maxime Faced with the exactly same problem. Did you resolve it?

Comment: If I remembrer correctly, I used the XML format to transmit the data back to Parse